# get object from array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to access the property of an object in an array, but I keep getting an error saying that the array value is nil:

```
@notifications.each do |note|
  @users << User.find(note.notifier_id)
end

@unreads = []
for i in 0..@users.count
  @unreads[i] = 0
  @current_user.notifications.each do |n|
    if n.notifier_id == @users[i].id && n.seen == false
      @unreads[i] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass):`, coming from `@users[i].id`

If I don't run that for loop and just print out the value of `@users`, I get the expected output, which includes valid `id` values.

How do I properly access a `User` object from an array?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to let your database do this?

Comment: how do you mean? Index on seen?

Comment: You can do all of this with ActiveRecord queries.

Comment: I think @sawa probably solved your problem. That solution will not prevent a `NoMethodError` if `User.find` ever returns `nil`, though.

Comment: @Jordan thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of accessing is correct, but you are trying to access `@users` at an index that does not exist. Try:

```
for i in 0...@users.count
```

Comment: isn't that exactly what I have?

Comment: Three dots vs two. Three dots excludes the final number, two dots includes it. Arrays in ruby are zero indexed, so an array of 10 items would have indexes 0 through 9, not 0 through 10.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your code.

### 1. Off-by-one Error

The first issue will always be a problem. As @sawa answered, you have an off-by-one error in the range you're using in your `for` loop. Use three dots:

```
for i in 0...@users.count
```

instead of two dots:

```
for i in 0..@users.count
```

The [Ruby 2.3.0 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) for the `Range` class reads:

> Ranges constructed using `..` run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using `...` exclude the end value.

### 2. Potential `nil` Result in Query

It's possible that `User.find(note.notifier_id)` will return `nil`. Unlike problem #1, this may not always happen. I'm not assuming you're using Rails in my suggestions below, since you didn't mention using it.

One way to deal with this is to ensure that `User.find` *always* returns an object that responds to `#id`. This would be an instance of `User` in most cases, and possibly a null object when the query can't find a `User` record. You can see an example of the null object pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#Ruby).

Another way to deal with this is to check to see if `@users[i]` is present before sending it the `#id` message.

```
@notifications.each do |note|
  @users << User.find(note.notifier_id)
end

@unreads = []
for i in 0...@users.count
  @unreads[i] = 0
  @current_user.notifications.each do |n|
    if @users[i] && n.notifier_id == @users[i].id && n.seen == false
      @unreads[i] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

If `@users[i]` is `nil`, the code won't ever execute `@users[i].id`. Adding the extra check to the conditional makes the code harder to read, however.

You could also discard `nil` values from your `@users` array with [`#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) before counting the number of unread items. I'm using [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) below, since it's a bit more idiomatic than `for`.

```
@notifications.each do |note|
  @users << User.find(note.notifier_id)
end

@unreads = []
@users.compact.each_with_index do |user, i|
  @unreads[i] = 0
  @current_user.notifications.each do |n|
    if n.notifier_id == @users[i].id && n.seen == false
      @unreads[i] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the second issue. It wouldn't be a problem now since Users cannot be deleted, but account deletion will eventually be implemented, so that was a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

from `0..@users.count`, there are `@user.count + 1` elements, but you can access by index from `0..(@users.count-1)`.
it is better for using `each_with_index` to loop in @users

```
@users.each_with_index do |user, i|
  @unreads[i] = @current_user.
    notifications.
    where(notifier_id: user.id, seen: false).
    count
end
```

Shorter version

```
@users = User.where(id: @notifications.map(&:notifier_id)) 
@unreads = @users.map { |user| @current_user.notifications.where(notifier_id: user.id, seen: false).count }
```